# Prevent request getting resubmiited on quick clicks with <h:commandButton

Tags: jsf

I have a project where user will submit the form and server will go some processing. I am facing an issue where user clicks the submit button twice too quickly and that causes exception on the server. What I am trying to do is to prevent double clicks without disabling the button (that's the requirement from client :( ) .The code snippet is :

```
<h:commandButton id="create_acct_btn" styleClass="common_btn" value="#{msg['ui.text.login.create']}">
                <f:ajax listener="#{termsPageBean.createAccount}" render="@form" event="click" onevent="createAccountClick"/>
            </h:commandButton>
```

function createAccountClick(event) { 
                    if (event.status == "success") {

```
                    if($('#createAccountResult').val() === 'true') { 
                        $.blockUI({ message: $('#create1'), css: { width: '275px', left: $(document).width()/2 - (275 / 2), border : '0px',
                            },
                    focusInput: false,
                    overlayCSS:{cursor:"default"}
                     });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, you can, for instance, **unbind the "click"** event when the event.status="begin" and **restore it** when the event.status="success" (or failure, etc).

Hope this helps.